# Redirect all images to its corresponding https site

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect all the images to its corresponding https version url,

For example: `http:// example.com/abc.png` to `https:// example.com/abc.png` and `http:// www.example.com/abc.png` to `https:// www.example.com/abc.png`

I tried following

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wahab.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.wahab.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https ://% {HTTP_HOST} %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

But redirect loops 
Any ideas?

Note: i added extra spaces in urls to avoid warnings and restrictions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course it loops - because the pattern matches for requests for the HTTPS versions as well (since only the url *path* component is checked). Add a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) that checks if the request came in via HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, i know that, I tried to add below code before non http check,
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on But i do not know what to do if this condition met ?

Comment: You _don’t_ want to do one single thing when the condition is met: _Rewrite!_ (Meaning, _because if I’ll let you figure this one out by yourself as well we’ll drag this out for too long probably:_ __Negate__ your condition, so that the URL _only_ gets rewritten if the request was _not_ made via HTTPS already.)

Comment: So what's the final answer to this :) ?  I can't decode your comments here.

Comment: @jDelforge `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` would be one way to check that it is off, checking that the value is `!=on` would be another way.